# Does Netty's WriteCompletionEvent guarantees that other side have recieved my data or only that I'v sent data to the network?

Tags: java, netty

Does Netty's WriteCompletionEvent guarantees TCP push acknoledgement [PSH, ACK] or just push [PSH] of packets of sent data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*TCP* doesn't provide an arrival guarantee on an individual `send()`: only  implicitly if all subsequent sends and the `close()` work, so Netty certainly can't do that either.

Comment: e.g. Wikipedia says: «TCP provides reliable, ordered delivery of a stream of bytes from a program on one computer to another program on another computer»

Comment: So, Netty could generate WriteCompletionEvent either when TCP part transmitted all data into network (sent all [PSH] packets) or when TCP part received approval of all data receiving (received [PSH][ACK] packets for all sent packets).

Comment: @Errandir (1) that's what I mean by 'implicit', although I get my information about TCP from RFC793, not Wikipedia, and (2) Netty can't possibly know about either of those events. There is nothing in the Sockets API that will tell it. All it can know is that it has written your data into the TCP send buffer.

Comment: "..TCP doesn't provide an arrival guarantee.." This is untrue. ref: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol

Comment: @user1843591 Again, that's exactly what I mean by 'implicitly', and again, you can't cite Wikipedia as a normative reference.

Comment: Anyone else who wants to cite Wikipedia against this answer should note that I contributed part of that entry myself. It doesn't contradict what I've said.